# Nothing happening on jQuery post

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, post

Below is my jQuery function that is used to post the values of name, password and email to `register.php` and then display a message echoed in `register.php` in`div#message`.

However when I click the `postBtn` nothing happens and the console does not log clicked.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnPost").on("click", function() {
        console.log('clicked'); 
        var thisBtn = $(this); 
        var parent = thisBtn.parent(); 

        name = parent.data('name'); 
        password = parent.data('password'); 
        email = parent.data('email');

        $.post(
            'register.php', 
            { 
                name: ('name'), 
                password: ('password'), 
                email: ('email')
            },          
            function(data) {
                parent.next('#message').html(data);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

This is the HTML block where all the data is input, however nothing seems to be happening when the button `#postBtn` is clicked.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Username: <td>
        <td> <input type = "text"  class = "field" name = "name"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Password: <td>
        <td> <input type = "password" class = "field" name = "password"> </td>
    </tr>
        <td > Email: <td>
        <td> <input type = "email" class = "field" name = "email"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  <td>
        <td> <button  class='regular' id = "btnPost" name='save'> Log In  </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works when I throw up a jsFiddle. Do you have other code that might be conflicting with the above?

Comment: Your code seems fine - assuming you're using jQuery 1.7+ and have access to `on()`. Are there any errors on the console before you click `#btnPost`?

Comment: You might need to work on your HTML formatting... just for consistency and readability.  Different "/', different spaces around = signs, etc...  Also, why not make this an HTML form so it work when js is disabled?

Comment: Also, what browser are you testing in?

Comment: please link to the js fiddle, i dont want to make it a form because then the whole page will refresh after the button is clicked

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bUsBN/ Here's what I tried.  Worked as well.

Comment: nothing happens when the log in button is clicked

Comment: Check the console log.  Knowing what browser you're in would help significantly.

Comment: ive checked the log, im in chrome

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8132/discussion-between-foshoeiyyy-and-stuart-branham)

Comment: There were serious issues with HTML and I edited it, as well as added a line and changed the JS to match what I posted below... See http://jsfiddle.net/bUsBN/3/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to yourself using the same syntax, I re-worked mine to something along the following lines and it solved the issue....

try:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnPost", function() { //implementation });
```

You can change `$(document)` to the name of a containing div, or something at a lower-level, so long as `#btnPost` is contained within it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bUsBN/3/ - the event fires, I write something to the screen. If something fails in the middle then it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of jQuery library files included in to the source(HTML). First jQuery library file and then your javascript file. It seems your code is working fine in jsfiddle. one of the reason may be the jQuery file is not there or loading order may be mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your use of `.next()`, which returns the next sibling of the current element.  And since you are passing in a selector, you will only get a result if the next sibling satisfies the selector, otherwise you get nothing.  Just use `$("#message")` since `#message` is not the next sibling following the parent element of your button.

```
$.post( 
    'register.php',  
    {  
        name: ('name'),  
        password: ('password'),  
        email: ('email') 
    },           
    function(data) { 
        $('#message').html(data); 
    } 
);
```