# Nothing display in div after post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register button[name=btnPosta]").click(function() {
        console.log('clicked');

        thisBtn = $(this);
        parent = $(this).parent();
        name = parent.data('name');

        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        $.post('register.php', {
            name: ('name')
        }, function(data) {
            console.log('Ajax success');
            parent.next('#message').html(data);
            thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset  });

            console.log('Ajax success');
        });
    });
});​
```

This function is used to display name in the #message `div`
however nothing gets displayed in the `div`.

Comment: Tried debugging with dev tools like firebug to see what response you're getting?

Comment: Are you seeing the console message?

Comment: Do you see "Ajax success" on your console?

Comment: Post your HTML.  I suspect that the `message` div isn't where you expect it is in the DOM.

Comment: By the looks of it, you're trying to use multiple elements with the same `message` ID, which can lead to weird bugs and it's simply wrong. If that's the case, change it into a class and change your selector to `.message`. IDs should be unique, if there is only one `#message` element, then `$('#message').html(data);` should do the trick.

Comment: id is unique, i dont use it any where else

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nothing happening on jQuery post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417079/nothing-happening-on-jquery-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your markup is similar to the markup you posted in [your duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417079/nothing-happening-on-jquery-post) from an hour ago:

```
...
<tr> 
    <td>  <td> 
    <td> <button  class='regular' id = "btnPost" name='save'> Log In  </button></td> 
</tr> 
...
```

The problem is in your use of `.next()`.  When you pass a selector argument to `.next()`, you only get a result if the next sibling element matches the selector.  Your call to `parent.next("#message")` returns an empty jQuery object because:

1. The next sibling of the button's parent element (which is the `<td>`) does not have an id of `message`.
2. Actually, there is no next sibling of that `<td>`.

Since `parent.next("#message")` returns an empty jQuery object, calling `.html()` on it has no effect.  The solution is just to use `$("#message")` directly:

```
$('#message').html(data);
```

---

My [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9418857/1) was just a red herring:

<s>Make sure to use the `var` keyword when defining your variables.  Without `var`, you are creating a property on the `Global` object (or `window` when running JavaScript inside a browser).  But, `parent` is already a property of `window`.  In IE, `window.parent` is read-only, so your value is never set and you will get an error when you call `parent.data()`.</s>

Your code works for me when I use `var`: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/MkS9X/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#register").find("button[name=btnPosta]").click(function() {
        console.log('clicked');

        //notice the use of `var` to keep the variables local, which will be faster
        var thisBtn = $(this),
            parent  = thisBtn.parent(),
            name    = parent.data('name');

        //notice the use of `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`, `.prop()` is new as of jQuery 1.6, so if you are using an older version then `.attr()` is the way to go
        thisBtn.prop('disabled', true);
        $.post('register.php', {
            name: name //notice here that this references the `name` variable set further up
        }, function(data) {
            console.log('Ajax success');

            parent.next('#message').html(data);
            thisBtn.prop('disabled', false); // reset  });

            console.log('Ajax success');
        });
    });
});​
```

Just a couple suggestions for your code. Mainly the variables were being created in the global scope for most likely no reason.